# How do I make a group of functions loop swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My problem is I am trying to make all the bar6s to move down to the bottom of the screen, similar to flappy bird. I've done most of it, what I've done is make the bars go
down but I want to make it go on forever but only 5 bars go down how can I make it go on forever like regenerate or can you make a completion block in the function while you declare it.

Here is my code:

```
//
//  PlaysScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket3
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 27/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import spriteKit

class PlayScene:SKScene {
    //declaring the node in this scene!
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

    let bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar1")

    let bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar2")

    let bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar3")

    let bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar4")

    let bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar5")

    let bar6a = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6b = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6c = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6d = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6e = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6f = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6g = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6h = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6i = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6j = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    //making actions

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var check1 = false
        var check2 = false
        var check3 = false
        var check4 = false
        var check5 = false


        var delayA = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.5))
        var delayB = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2))
        var delayC = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(4))
        var delayD = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(6))
        var delayE = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(8))
        var actionmove = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 15)
        var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.5))
        var sequence = SKAction.sequence([ delay , actionmove])
        var delchild = SKAction.removeFromParent()


        func f1 () {
            bar6a.position = CGPointMake(800 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6b.position = CGPointMake(1600,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            check1 = false

            bar6a.runAction(actionmove)
            bar6b.runAction(actionmove,completion: {
                self.bar6a.position = CGPointMake(800 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
                self.bar6b.position = CGPointMake(1600,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
                check1 = true
                self.bar6a.runAction(actionmove)
                self.bar6b.runAction(actionmove,completion: {
                    self.bar6a.removeFromParent()
                    self.bar6b.removeFromParent()

                    check1 = true


                })

            })

            actionmove.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut


        }


        var sequence2 = SKAction.sequence([ delayB ,actionmove])
        var sequence3 = SKAction.sequence([ delayC ,actionmove])
        var sequence4 = SKAction.sequence([ delayD ,actionmove])
        var sequence5 = SKAction.sequence([delayE , actionmove])


        bar6a.xScale = 2.5
        bar6b.xScale = 2.5
        bar6c.xScale = 2.5
        bar6d.xScale = 2.5
        bar6e.xScale = 2.5
        bar6f.xScale = 2.5
        bar6g.xScale = 2.5
        bar6h.xScale = 2.5
        bar6i.xScale = 2.5
        bar6j.xScale = 2.5



        //making the actions

        var num1 = 1
        //making different delays

        //sequence actions


        addChild(bar6a)
        addChild(bar6b)
        addChild(bar6c)
        addChild(bar6d)
        addChild(bar6e)
        addChild(bar6f)
        addChild(bar6g)
        addChild(bar6h)
        addChild(bar6i)
        addChild(bar6j)



        //making the functions



        func f2 () {
            check2 = false

            bar6c.position = CGPointMake(400 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6d.position = CGPointMake(1200,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6d.runAction(sequence2)
            bar6c.runAction(sequence2, completion:{
            self.bar6c.removeFromParent()
            self.bar6d.removeFromParent()
                check2 = true

            })
            bar6d.runAction(sequence2)
        }

        func f3 () {
            check3 = false

            bar6e.position = CGPointMake(600 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6f.position = CGPointMake(1400,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))

            bar6e.runAction(sequence3,completion:{
            self.bar6e.removeFromParent()
            self.bar6f.removeFromParent()
                check3 = true

            })
            bar6f.runAction(sequence3)


        }

        func f4 () {
            check4 = false
            bar6g.position = CGPointMake(700 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6h.position = CGPointMake( 1500,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6h.runAction(sequence4)
            bar6g.runAction(sequence4,completion:{
            self.bar6g.removeFromParent()
            self.bar6h.removeFromParent()
            check4 = true


            })



        }

        func f5 () {
            check5 = false
            bar6i.position = CGPointMake(700 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6j.position = CGPointMake(1500 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6j.runAction(sequence5)
            bar6i.runAction(sequence5,completion:{
            check5 = true
                self.bar6i.removeFromParent()
                self.bar6j.removeFromParent()


            })



        }

            f1()
            f2()
            f3()
            f4()
            f5()

                //making the action repeat forever

        var num2 = 1


        bar1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY (self.frame))
        bar2.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY (self.frame))
        bar3.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY (self.frame))
        bar4.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY (self.frame))
        bar5.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY (self.frame))

        bar1.xScale = 2.5
        bar2.xScale = 2.5
        bar3.xScale = 2.5
        bar4.xScale = 2.5
        bar5.xScale = 1.7







        /*
        bar1.runAction(sequence, completion: {
            self.bar2.runAction(sequence, completion: {
                self.bar3.runAction(sequence, completion:{
                    self.bar4.runAction(sequence, completion:{
                    self.bar5.runAction(sequence)
                    })
                    })
            })
            })*/


        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        //doing the background stuff
        background.yScale = 2.0
        background.xScale = 3.0
        addChild(background)
                //doing the the bar stuff
        if check1 == true{

           f1()

        }
}


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    }
}
```

Comment: you have a lot of variables there, would it be easier to use an array (`bars[1]`) or dictionary (`delays["A"]`) ?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I see that you are trying to do this similar to flappy bird now. I would suggest doing either an SKPhysicsNode with spritekit or attempting to use Cocos2d http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics

Comment: ok trying it please keep online so if it does not work  you can help me thanks.

Comment: no it does not work i want it to go down sort of like flappy bird

Comment: Oh, I am guessing that you are looking for SKPhysicsBody then https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html in order to simulate gravity.
I will edit the original answer to fit your need.

Comment: I can't find anything helpful in that site

Comment: If you don't want to use cocos2d you can just mess with an SKPhysicsbody. Create a physics body for the scene, then give the bird a physics body as well so it falls.

Comment: no it is similar to flappy bird but not the same I want the bars to go down and loop it